# get clicked button via html

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to get pressed key like:

```
<button id="myBtn"  onkeydown="keydownFunction()" >
```

and then in js:

```
function keydownFunction(e){
  alert(e.code);
}
```

Note I **don't** want to use `documnent.getElementById("myKey").addEventListener()...` I want the event declared via html like above

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve?
keydown means there is a key pressed on the keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can. We just need to pass `event` object to the function like `onkeydown="keydownFunction(event)"`, then press tab to set the focus back to the `myBtn` button and when the button has focus then you can press and a single key to get the code.

```js
function keydownFunction(e){
  console.log(e.code);
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" onkeydown="keydownFunction(event)">Click Me</button>
```

Also, if you don't pass the `event` in the HTML markup, then still we can access the event inside `keydownFunction` function like:

```js
function keydownFunction(e){
  e = e || window.event
  console.log(e.code);
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" onkeydown="keydownFunction()">Click Me</button>
```